# Module pattern JavaScript - scroll event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement module pattern in JS but scroll event not firing, whats wrong with the code, following the example

```js
var modBrandHeader = (function ($) {
    'use strict';
  
    var $con;
  
    /* GENERIC */
    var init = function () {
      $con = $('.brand-header');
      if (!$con.length) {
        return;
      }
    };

    var scroll = function (scrollTop) {
      if (scrollTop > $('.brand-header').height()) {
          console.log("Scroll");
      } else {
        console.log("Scroll removed");
      }
    };

    return {
      init: init,
      scroll: scroll
    };
  })(jQuery);
```

```css
.brand-header {
  height:70px;
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  background-color:#ddd;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="brand-header">This is header</div>
```

Comment: You never ask your code to do anything other than load up the function. What do you believe causes _**the scroll event to fire**_ in your words.

Comment: I am belive scroll event should fire when I scroll the page since I am returing the `scroll` with `init`

Comment: Scroll event will definitely fire when you scroll the page...but that has nothing to do with your code. You should research the difference between a function and an event listener. All you have here is the function with no event listener. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong (or at least non-ideal) here.  First, you are not tying anything to the scroll event.  It appears that you believe that your `scroll` function will be called when that event fires, but it will not.  You need to add something like:

```
$(document).on("scroll", scroll);
```

You can place this where you want (after the scroll function is defined anyway), but it would be typical and recommended to place this into your init function, wrapped in a `$(document).ready` block.

Next, nothing actually calls your `init` function, though perhaps this is called by code not displayed here.  You will need to call that one way or another; it will not happen automatically.

Finally, your `init` function has a pointless if/return block; if there is no `$con` you return, but you do that anyway because there is no further functionality there.

One last tip: scroll events are typically not rate-limited by a browser.  (Or at least, not to the point that you probably expect them to be.)  This event will fire a *lot* and you may want to add your own rate-limiting for any event that you call as a result.  If you don't, performance will likely degrade especially on longer pages.